# How can I prevent fs.readdirSync interpreting commas in file names as seperate files?

Tags: node.js, express

I try to read the content of a folder with fs.readDirSync, problem is: file names containing commas are interpreted as multiple files, same goes for folders...

So far I've tried replacing comma values with escape sequences, which I found out is unnecessary in JS...

```
let dirContent = fs.readdirSync(`${dir}`);
let files = [];
let folders = [];

dirContent.map(object => {
    fs.statSync(dir + "/" + object).isDirectory()
        ? folders.push(object)
        : files.push(object);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it does that? Doesn't do that on my machine. Commas in filenames return a single file. What version of node are you running? I tested on node 8.11.1 and 9.4.0

Comment: Also, what OS are you running on? I tested on Mac and Linux and it works as you expect it to - not split filenames with commas